# How to return JSON result from a custom exception filter?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to create a custom exception filter that will catch exceptions thrown in controller actions that return JSON results.

I would like to refactor the following action method:

```
        public JsonResult ShowContent()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some business logic work that might throw a business logic exception ...
            //throw new ApplicationException("this is a business exception");

            var viewModel = new DialogModel
                                {
                                    FirstName = "John",
                                    LastName = "Doe"
                                };

            // Other exceptions that might happen:
            //throw new SqlException(...);
            //throw new OtherException(...);
            //throw new ArgumentException("this is an unhandeled exception");

            return
                Json(
                    new
                        {
                            Status = DialogResultStatusEnum.Success.ToString(),
                            Page = this.RenderPartialViewToString("ShowContent", viewModel)
                        });
        }
        catch (ApplicationException exception)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = DialogResultStatusEnum.Error.ToString(), Page = exception.Message });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = DialogResultStatusEnum.Exception.ToString(), Page = "<h2>PROBLEM!</h2>" });
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is create a custom exception filter attribute that will catch any exceptions thrown in the action follow the following logic:

1. Check if there was an exception

   - No: return
   - yes:

     - If BusinessLogic exception – return a JSON result
     - If other unhandled exception:

       - Log
       - Return another JSON result with a different result code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found it possible to solve this problem using the code found in [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=496) (with minor changes to it.)

```
public class HandleJsonExceptionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Instance Methods

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    Error = filterContext.Exception.Message
                }
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I agrees this should be the correct answer.  However, there is a bug (?) in 1.1 that requires not setting ExceptionHandled to true.  If you do the body of the response will be empty.

Comment: Can `ExceptionFilterAttribute` be used instead? (I was not able to find the class `ActionExecutedContext`).

Answer (score -2):

```
  public class YourController : BaseController
    {
        public JsonResult showcontent()
        {
            // your logic here to return foo json
            return Json ( new { "dfd" }); // just a dummy return text replace it wil your code
        }
    }

    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
 // Catch block for all exceptions in your controller
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
            if (filterContext.Exception.Equals(typeof(ApplicationException)))
            {
                //do  json and return
            }
            else
            {
                // non applictaion exception
// redirect to generic error controllor and error action which will return json result

            }
        }

    }
```

Refer this link to see how to create and use [HandleError attribute](http://erikzaadi.com/blog/2009/12/22/AspdotNETMVCExceptionHandlingWithJQuery.xhtml)

****EDIT*** for HandleAttribute for Actions*

```
//not tested code
public class HandleErrorfilter : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
         public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
                string message = string.Empty;
                //if application exception
                // do  something
                 else
                    message = "An error occured while attemting to perform the last action.  Sorry for the inconvenience.";
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnException(filterContext);
            }
        }

      public class YourController : BaseController
        {
            [HandleErrorfilter]
            public JsonResult showcontent()
            {
                // your logic here to return foo json
                return Json ( new { "dfd" }); // just a dummy return text replace it wil your code
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you swapneel but I would like to create a filter attribute that I will use to decorate my controller actions that return JSON - I am not looking into overriding the OnException method.

Comment: you have requested for - custom exception filter attribute   in your question?

Comment: see my *EDIT for HandleAttribute for Actions*